Game of discs inside a square
A 3*3 square is given. Two players alternate in placing discs of 1 unit diameter inside the square. A disc can be placed if it doesn't overlap another disc or the edge of the square, it can however touch them. The player who cannot place a disc is declared the loser.
Does any player have a winning strategy?

Same as this?

Very similar, but not the same. Here we have a square playing field of a given size.

But the winning strategy is exactly the same regardless...? If anything, this is just a specific example of the more general puzzle.

Yep agree. Turns out it is the same.

one winning strategy for

 'first' player

seems to

 place first disc exactly in the middle

then

 wherever opponent 'next' places a disc, first player can

react placing next disc

 mirror of opponent place with respect to center of square

